# Having to add library files manually. Why?

Tags: android, eclipse, libraries

I'm having this weird issue on my Eclipse:

Once I load it I get an error with the support-v4.jar, deleted it from the project libs and added as external jar file @ Jata Build Path - problem solved

Then I had the same problem with roboguice libs and this went on for ALL my project libs. Can anyone help me with that? It's a pain to delete and add manually all libs everytime that I pull this project from my group's git repo.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using lib folder or libs folder for storing your libraries ?

Comment: I'm using just the project default libs folder, I have to add em' manually from there. Seems that Eclipse is not reading it.

The only external libs are sherlock and facebook but those are fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way to deal whit this problem is using MAVEN, add dependency and never have a headache.

Usefull links:

> http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBuildMaven/article.html
>
> https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/

Cheers